# Is it possible to have intellisense in VSCode show the return type?

Tags: unity-game-engine, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I've switched from MonoDevelop to VSCode for C# development for Unity3d.
The intellisence provided by MonoDevelop IMO was more informative.

As you type MonoDevelop gives you useful things like whether the item in the list is a method, property or primitive etc and also the return type.
VSCode does not do this, here's an example of the as you type completion.

//edit I cannot use Visual Studio as I'm using Mac OSX. Switching to Windows bootcamp just for Unity is not convenient or productive.

**VSCode**

[image: VSCode Completion]

**MonoDevelop**

[image: MD Completion]

Comment: Just use visual studio.

Comment: I'm on a Mac @Programmer otherwise I would.

Comment: MonoDevelop is not perfect but there is nothing better on Mac for Mono nad Unity3D. And @Programmer, one uses mac with Unity3D not only to build for iOS - it has many powerful tools and first of all it is UNIX.

Comment: @Programer, TBH I would have expected a more informed response from someone with your rep. I don't just develop for Unity, Switching into Windows just for VS is not convenient or productive. My Question is about improving intellisense in VSCode.

Comment: @Rob It's not an answer. I put that as a suggestion. That comment was made based on experience. I've tried many IDE's on Mac and came to conclusion that life is easier with Visual Studio when working with Unity. You can also use visual machine that doesn't require switching to another OS by booting.

Comment: I'd agree with @Programmer that life with Unity is going to be easier for you on Windows, mostly because Unity Technologies & Microsoft have been working together on a ton of stuff for the last few years, so it makes sense that a lot of useful tools will come out for Windows before OSX.

Comment: @StevenMills I don't doubt that, I use Windows too but with respect the question is rather specific and wasn't inviting opinion or discussion about platforms as SO isn't the place for that. Whilst I appreciate the sentiment I've worked with Unity on Mac for ~2 years without issue. Lets try and keep the discussion on topic, if the answer is "No" that's fine.

Comment: You probably have a free edition of VS coz I see return value in mine.

Comment: @Everts This is VSCode not VS

Comment: You probably already checked but [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) contains a lot of useful information on C# in VSCode.

Comment: Thanks @LucasBader I have, it's actually because I have to use an old version of omnisharp and the legacy-csharp extension to work with Unity3d. There are loads of improvements in the latest version of omnisharp included what I've actually asked for here.

Comment: Hi, there is is a visual studio for Mac now. It is still in beta. Just to let you know.

Comment: I saw,haven't tried it yet. It doesn't really seem necessary as we don't need any of the visual elements for Unity development only the script editor and debugging? VSCode is decent replacement for MonoDevelop in my experience, given the issue I here is solved by the newest version of VSCode I haven't found myself needing anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete is largely driven by the Omnisharp extension for VSCode.

<strike>Due to issues with compatibility of Unity extensions the latest c# extensions for VSCode it's required that for Unity3d development the [legacy C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.omnisharp) is used.</strike>

The Legacy c# extension uses an old version of Omnisharp that does not have a very up-to-date feature set for autocomplete.

Return type has been added to [more recent versions](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/287) of Omnisharp.

**//Edit**

It's now recommended to use the latest C# extension of VSCode, the Legacy is no longer required for Unity Development so we can now benefit from improved Omnisharp integration in VSCode when developing for Unity3d. Yay!